# IPagedList localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using third party component (`IPagedList` ) to implement pagination. Everything works fine,   I just need to localize message for example

```
Showing items 11 through 11 of 11.
```

This message text is generated using `PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText`

Comment: Check [HERE](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to set custom localized format:

```
var options = new PagedListRenderOptions();
options.PageCountAndCurrentLocationFormat = "Page {0} of {1}."; //your custom string goes gere
options.ItemSliceAndTotalFormat = "Showing items {0} through {1} of {2}.";
```